# How to stop batch execution when maven build fails

Tags: java, maven, batch-file

I have a batch file to make my life easy.

I want to build a maven project then copy the distribution from the target folder to another folder, then unzip them and followed by few copy replace instructions. This works perfectly fine when there is no issue with the code.

If there is any issue with the build and build fails then I want to stop the batch execution.

I am not able to figure it out.

```
::Kill all the java processs
taskkill /f /im "java.exe"

::Take the sprint number form the user
set /p sprintNumber=Enter the sprint number:%=%

:: Navigate to the code path
cd D:\Sprint-%sprintNumber%
call D:

:: Build the code

::@echo ###############BUILDING####################
::call mvn clean install

::cd ..

::Remove the distribution
IF EXIST "D:\Distribution\Sprint-%sprintNumber%\" (
    rmdir "D:\Distribution\Sprint-%sprintNumber%\" /s /q
)
::Few more instructions
```

I want to stop my execution if maven install fails. Please provide any suggestion to acheive  this task.

Comment: Probably by testing exit code (`%errorlevel%` under windows if I remember well).

Comment: You should probably use a build server for this kind of stuff (checkout jenkins or ...)

Comment: @RC.: Thank you for you suggestion but I have some constraints on my side. I use any other software(s). I will try using `errorlevel`. :)

Answer (score 8):

On the line after the build command add something like

```
if errorlevel 1 echo An error occurred & pause & goto :EOF
```